# Como modelar ações/processos do sistema

Tags: modelagem

Vou tentar explicar o que tenho em mão e qual minha dúvida.

Estou modelando um sistema que irá controlar todos os contratos da empresa já comecei a identificar os objetos desses sistema e também o seu processo e ai que surgiu minha duvida: O processo dentro do sistema é uma sequência de ações ou um objeto também?

**Assinatura do processo**

Vou descrever um dos processos que já identifiquei que é o de assinatura de contrato feito logo apos a negociação.

Ao receber um contrato o setor logístico envia o mesmo ao setor jurídico para validação ou correção que depois encaminhado de volta ao logístico que por sua vez encaminha a diretoria para assinatura e de volta ao setor logístico vai para a assinatura do fornecedor e volta ao logístico para arquivamento.

Minha dúvida é o contrato ganha uma sequência de status ou o Processo de Assinatura se torna um objeto no meu sistema?

Comment: Isso tá com cara de BPM. Dá uma olhada [nisso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerenciamento_de_processos_de_neg%C3%B3cio). Eu iria pela ideia de o contrato ser uma entidade com status.

Comment: Qual tecnologia está usando? (Removi as tags [tag:java] e [tag:C#] pq acho que você não está usando as duas, certo?)